# Can you fix rubber on a handle after it has all but turned into a liquid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, polymers

I picked up a splitting maul at a yard sale last year. I used it for the rest of the season with no problems. It has been in the wood shed and exposed to some sun, but mostly shade.

I picked it up the other day and it stuck to my hand. When I tried to let go, it slid from my hand, leaving behind black goo and rubber from the handle. Now it's so bad the whole rubber part is gooey and if I try to rub anything on it the rubber comes off. It's permanently soft and sticky and is coming off the handle.

Can I save it or is it done?

Comment: Suggestion: this should be moved to Lifehacks.

Comment: Take it off, then Plasti-Dip.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem with other types of rubber-coated tool handles. The best solution is to completely remove the rubber coating, which takes a *lot* of scraping and then scrubbing (outdoors) with paint thinner on paper towels. Invariably, as you have already noticed, everything touched gets coated with hard-to-remove black goop.

Another choice would be to wipe off the loose stuff and then over-wrap the handle with a strong cloth tape, *checking carefully that it will not slip* when you use the maul.

You might cover the tape with [heat-shrink tubing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MJVQR7I), if you have the right diameter stuff, or with tubing cut from an old bicycle inner-tube (cheap or free, and makes a good grip).